# How to retrieve byte array to image c#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying to retrieve an image saved in postgresql database in BYTEA format, but I'm having difficulties in transforming the byte array to image using C#. I'm getting "INVALID PARAMETERS" as a return. I've been trying for days and still haven't been able to. Can anyone help me?

```
    byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(mStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void dgv_empresa_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_empresa.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[9].Value);
        if (id != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string query = " SELECT p.photo_img " +
                        " FROM empresa as e, photo as p " +
                        " WHERE e.empresa_img = " + id + " AND " +
                        " e.empresa_img = p.photo_id; ";

                conexao.Open();
                dgv_empresa.Rows.Clear();
                DataTable dados = new DataTable();
                NpgsqlDataAdapter adaptador = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(query, conexao);
                adaptador.Fill(dados);

                Image imagem = null;

                if (dados.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow linha in dados.Rows)
                    {
                        byte[] binary = ObjectToByteArray(linha[0]);
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(binary, 0, binary.Length);
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        imagem = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                        Image i = byteArrayToImage(binary);
                    }
                }
                pct_Imagem.Image = imagem;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                conexao.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro no Banco de Dados!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                //dgv_empresa.Rows.Clear();
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Close();
            }
```

}

Comment: If you inserted the Image bytes in a BYTEA Column, then just cast the content to `byte[]`, then you have `var Image = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom([bytes]);` -- Your code is doing weird things: why are using a DataTable to retrieve an Image by ID, clear rows of a DataGridView, then start a loop... Just create a data reader and get the content of the first Column, cast to `byte[]`.

Comment: `BinsryFormatter` has no reason for being in this code, and won't produce a valid image file, that's for sure. Just save the image's binary data in the database directly, and read the `byte[]` directly.

Comment: Here, second result in a quick search: [How to insert and retrieve image from PostgreSql using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46128132/7444103) (the first, as usual, is ancient)

Comment: Gentlemen, I could see that the error is in converting the object returned by the database search to byte[], I tested the conversion between byte to image and from image to byte in numerous ways, and it worked, I tested applying it in the PictureBox itself, and also in an Image variable. It worked perfectly, I checked the Length of the byte[] returned, and I realized that the difference between the one returned without the search for the bank is huge.

Comment: When I convert from object to byte the Length returned greater than I could was 40. When I convert directly from byte to image the length is normal. Varying by image, one image was 647895, another was 57894, and both were successful in converting.